# How to transform cyclic feature like month if it can have different periods like 30 and 31 in machine learning

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, feature-engineering

General transformations like sine and cosine can be performed. But how to decide which as its max duration for the cyclic period?

Example:

```
np.sin(df.day*(2.*np.pi/30))  or  np.sin(df.day*(2.*np.pi/31))
np.cos(df.day*(2.*np.pi/30))  or  np.cos(df.day*(2.*np.pi/31))
```

how to decide to use which pair of transformation?

Comment: Actually it will not matter that much. Try once `np.sin(df.day*(2.*np.pi/30))` and once `np.sin(df.day*(2.*np.pi/31))` and then see whether you see any improvement in your validation metrics. IMO it doesn't matter.

Comment: or is it even better to use 30.5? avging both? dint hear it from anybody. just thought by myself..

Comment: Feature Engineering is an art. There is no right and wrong answer as it is. You need to try a lot and then come to some conclusion. Also the conclusion may vary dataset by dataset. In `GBM` type of algorithms or `deep-learning` you divide by any number, it will not matter if you have trained enough. But in `linear algorithms` like `Logistic Regression` it may matter..but again you need to try.

Comment: ya obviously deep learning is different, it doesnt need any too much transformations as it mimics the brain to learn more patterns by adding more layers and generalizations. But some people like me when dealing with a long dataset and a normal laptop without much heavy resources every run might take time. So finding the efficient way first time itself reduces lot of iterations.

Comment: If your dataset includes the month, you could normalize the day between 0 and 1 before putting it into `sin(2*pi*x)` or `cos(2*pi*x)`. Having the year you could even solve the problem of leap years (28/29 of February).